# How Do I Prevent the KendoGrid's RemoveRow Function from Prompting?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui

I'm using a Kendo Grid's removeRow function. It works, but it always prompts "Are you sure you want to delete this record?" whenever I programmatically remove a row. I've already done the decision-making as to whether or not the row should be removed, so I don't want this message to show up. Googling didn't help and I couldn't find any similar question on StackOverflow or Kendo's forum. I know I could change the code, but I was wondering if there's a way to configure the grid to just not show it? Another solution would maybe be to temporarily block confirm prompts, possibly? Not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `editable.confirmation` to `false` should do the trick:

```
kendoGrid( {
  editable: {
      confirmation: false
  }
})
```

Comment: Sweet. Worked. Originally, my Google-foo failed me. After seeing this, I was like "wait, I was setting editable to a string - 'popup' - before. What do I do now?" And while trying to look up the full configuration, I found an example just like this. The old string value is to a property on the editable object called mode. So you would then set editable to { confirmation: false, mode: 'popup' }. Also, I found out that if you want to change the confirmation message, you set the confirmation property to the new message. E.g. { confirmation: 'Are you sure you want to delete this widget?' }

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround that I just figured out, in the meantime. It works fine, but it's a bit hacky:

```
var oldConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function() { return true; };
grid.getKendoGrid().removeRow(selectedRow);
window.confirm = oldConfirm;
```

I'd still be interested in hearing about any disabling of the confirmation, however, and I'll accept that as the answer if it comes along.